# RewriteRule ^ - [L] AKA RewriteRule caret dash L

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, caret

While I could turn on Rewrite Logging and mess with this rule to figure out what it does (if anything), I bet someone already knows.  Here's the rule by itself:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Here it is in context:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

I guess it means "Match Everything".  I'd have thought that "Match Everything" would be a dot to make it more obvious that there is no missing code, and that regexp would error out if the caret was the only thing in it.  So I see the outside chance that it means something else.

Answer (score 24):

- `^` is a somewhat unorthodox way of saying "match anything", just as you say
- `-` means "take no action"
- `[L]` means "last rule" i.e. stop processing `RewriteRules` after this point

I assume there are other rules following this one, because this combination of `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` says that if the current request is for an **existing** file or directory, `mod_rewrite` should **ignore** any subsequent `RewriteRules`.

---

Expressed in code, this would be equivalent to:

```
do_rewrites(req)
{
  if (is_file(req) || is_dir(req))
    return;

  // other rules
  ...
}
```